# What lintel to use above bi-fold doors in man cave?

Tags: roof, steel

I'm building a man cave in the corner of my garden, the base is finished already, now I'm planning the build from the ground up

The structure will be 2.5 metres high and will have a flat roof (rubber). The images below show a very crude plan I did online just now

[image: Floor plan of man cave]

[image: Front view of man cave]

I will order some custom bi-fold doors to completely fill the area which shows patio doors, I have asked the makers of the doors if they can fit the doors using 45 degree brackets either side and they said they could - so these will be fitted to the brick work

The height of the doors will fill the area, meaning there won't be any brick work above it. Also, because the walls either side of the doors are at 45 degrees, what kind of support will I need above the doors - this will hold the roof up and will need to remain straight so as to not stress the doors which will be around 2.5 meters long

I presume that steel will be the best idea, but what shape will it need to be? Do I need to have a custom made lintel?

Comment: Style? I'm asking how I can support the roof above bi-fold doors.

Comment: Whips, misread, sorry.

Comment: I think the answer is going to depend partly on the roof construction and how rigid it is in that area. There are lots of sheds out there with double doors that seem to do just fine with normal door framing...

Comment: Also, the doors below have much less importance than the structure and weight above the hole in wall.

Comment: A wooden header supported by 2 studs would be the way I would do it. the only issue here is the header would need some kind of siding to finish it out.

Comment: Are you sure you want the doors opening in? Their swing radius will require a lot of unoccupied area inside the room.